# Find and replace a text among the files of a project

Tags: search, replace, text, builtin

How can I do a "find and replace a string" in the files of a project? Is there a **standard, built-in** way?

Comment: Maybe you can have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44919530/find-text-in-a-project-but-within-a-specific-folder/44922948#44922948

Comment: Define what you mean by “project” in terms of how emacs will know what’s in it or not. Example: “everything in directory X and it’s subdirectories.”

Comment: You ask for a "*standard, built-in*" way. Be aware that that is limiting, because Emacs itself has no "*standard, built-in*" definition of a "*project*". If you define that term more clearly for your question, it might help direct "*standard, built-in*" answers toward that definition. (Otherwise, a more useful question might drop the "*standard, built-in*" restriction. But even then it would help to say what you mean by "*project*".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dired` has a command `dired-do-find-regexp-and-replace`, which is bound to <kbd>Q</kbd> by default. Keep in mind it uses regular expressions.

Comment: And in Emacs before Emacs 25, the same key, `Q`, does the same thing, but differently - it is bound in Emacs 24 and prior to command `dired-do-query-replace-regexp`.

Comment: ok. and how can I just search for a text in files of a project  without replacing it?

Comment: @Rakori you can mark files that contain a regexp in dired with `% m`, or you can use `M-x grep`.

Answer (score 3):

Like said, there are no standard ways of doing complicated things in emacs. Assuming project is defined as a git repository, you can do the following:

Install abo-abo's swiper/ivy/councel, https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper, and wgrep from ELPA. Bind the necessary commands to keys of your choice, especially `ivy-occur` that is usually `C-c C-o` and wgrep (`C-x C-q`).

1. With a project file open in your active buffer, give command `councel-git-grep` and type in the string you want to find in all project files.
2. Press your `ivy-occur` key to have the found lines in an new buffer.
3. Launch write grep (`wgrep`) to do editing in the occur buffer.
4. Save and exit with `C-c C-c`.

Answer (score 1):

Since I am new to emacs, I needed to know every little step of the process.  This is what ultimately worked for me:

1. `C-x C-f` opens `'find-file` (or alternatively use `M-x` `'project-find-file` `RET`).
2. Hit `RET` or type a subdirectory and hit `RET`. At this point a list of files in the directory appears and your cursor gets focus there.
3. Use arrow keys to go up/down, and hit `m` to mark each file/folder you want to run find & replace on.
4. `M-x` `dired-do-find-regexp-and-replace` `RET` prompts you for a regex find string. Type it then hit `RET`.
5. Now it prompts you for a replace string. Type it then hit `RET`.
6. Now it brings you to found strings one-by-one. For each one, type `y` to perform the replacement or type `n` to leave it unchanged.